# Email attachments with html not visible on some devices

Tags: python, email, gmail, mime

I would like to send an html email with content-ID attachment (image directly in the message) and Content-Disposition attachment with is an xls file.

Depending the client mail I use, the xls file is not visible (for example on iPhone, iPad or Samsung).

I suppose I have not include the xls file in the correct Part of the mail but when I try to include it before the `MIMEMultipart('alternative')`, It doesn't work.

Has someone any idea on the source of the problem in the following code ?

```
import base64
import httplib2

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import mimetypes
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       XXX <br><br>
        Hereunder a short overview of market evolution :<br>
        <img src="cid:image1" height="600" width="600">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

to='test@gmail.com';
subject='XXX';
message_main = html;
attachment_paths = [('test.png'), '<image1>'),
                    ('2910e0f.xls', False)]


# Check https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'

# Location of the gmail.storage
STORAGE = Storage('gmail.storage')

# Start the OAuth flow to retrieve credentials
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
http = httplib2.Http()

# Try to retrieve credentials from storage or run the flow to generate them
credentials = STORAGE.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)

# Authorize the httplib2.Http object with our credentials
http = credentials.authorize(http)

## Save credentials to storage
# STORAGE.put(credentials)
# Build the Gmail service from discovery
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

message = MIMEMultipart('related') # 'alternative', 'multipart', 'mixed', related
message['to'] = to
message['from'] = "YYY@gmail.com"
message['subject'] = subject
message.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'

# Encapsulate the plain and HTML versions of the message body in an
# 'alternative' part, so message agents can decide which they want to     display.
msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message.attach(msgAlternative)

msg1 = MIMEText(message_main, 'plain')
msg2 = MIMEText(message_main, 'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msg1)
msgAlternative.attach(msg2)

for filename, link in attachment_paths:
    print '----'
    print filename
    print link
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)

    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
        content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)

    if main_type == 'text':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'image':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'audio':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    else:
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
        msg.set_payload(fp.read())
        fp.close()

    if not link:
        # msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
        # message.attach(msg)
        # pdf = open(filename, 'rb').read()
        # msgPdf = MIMEApplication(pdf, 'pdf') # pdf for exemple
        # msgPdf.add_header('Content-ID', '<pdf1>') # if no cid, client like MAil.app (only one?) don't show the attachment
        msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
        # msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename=filename)
    else:
        # Define the image's ID as referenced above
        msg.add_header('Content-ID', link)
        msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)

    message.attach(msg)

body = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}

# body = {'raw': base64.b64encode(message.as_string())}

# send it
try:
  message = (gmail_service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=body).execute())
  print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
  print(message)
except Exception as error:
  print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution consists in changing the initial multipart container to mixed and to attach file in two step process :

- Before the `MIMEMultipart('alternative')` declaration for simple attachment
- After the `MIMEMultipart('alternative')` declaration for attachment which is related to html body (mainly for picture inside the message)

You can find hereunder the correct code :

```
import base64
import httplib2

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import mimetypes
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       XXX <br><br>
        Hereunder a short overview of market evolution :<br>
        <img src="cid:image1" height="600" width="600">
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

to='test@gmail.com';
subject='XXX';
message_main = html;
attachment_paths_html = [('test.png'), '<image1>')]
attachment_paths_mixed = [('2910e0f.xls', '2910e0f.xls')]

# Check https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'

# Location of the gmail.storage
STORAGE = Storage('gmail.storage')

# Start the OAuth flow to retrieve credentials
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
http = httplib2.Http()

# Try to retrieve credentials from storage or run the flow to generate them
credentials = STORAGE.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)

# Authorize the httplib2.Http object with our credentials
http = credentials.authorize(http)

## Save credentials to storage
# STORAGE.put(credentials)
# Build the Gmail service from discovery
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

message = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
message['to'] = to
message['from'] = "YYY@gmail.com"
message['subject'] = subject
message.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'


for filename, name in attachment_paths_mixed:
    print '----'
    print filename
    print name
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)

    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
        content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)

    if main_type == 'text':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'image':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'audio':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    else:
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
        msg.set_payload(fp.read())
        fp.close()

        msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=name)
        message.attach(msg)

# Encapsulate the plain and HTML versions of the message body in an
# 'alternative' part, so message agents can decide which they want to     display.
msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message.attach(msgAlternative)

msg1 = MIMEText(message_main, 'plain')
msg2 = MIMEText(message_main, 'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msg1)
msgAlternative.attach(msg2)

for filename, link in attachment_paths_html:
    print '----'
    print filename
    print link
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)

    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
        content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)

    if main_type == 'text':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'image':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'audio':
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
        fp.close()
    else:
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
        msg.set_payload(fp.read())
        fp.close()

        # Define the image's ID as referenced above
        msg.add_header('Content-ID', link)
        message.attach(msg)

body = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}

# body = {'raw': base64.b64encode(message.as_string())}

# send it
try:
  message = (gmail_service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=body).execute())
  print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
  print(message)
except Exception as error:
  print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
```